# removing seasonal trend in R

Tags: r

I have daily data for a period of 10 years(2000-2009), and I want to identify the seasonal cycle, remove it, and using these "detrended" data in regression analysis. For that, I am using ts and stl as:

```
           tm <- ts(a, start = 2000, freq = 365.25)
           tm2 <- stl(tm, s.window="periodic")
           x.sa <- seasadj(tm2)
```

When I plot the "trend" , I have a weird plot:

```
            plot(a,col="grey")
            lines(x.da,col="red")
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong in the plot?

I am quite new in time series and I am worried about the process, as far I know it should be ok, but I am not sure if the resulting time series (x.sa) would be OK (without the "seasonal cycle") to do multiple regression with the new "detrended" data.

**EDIT:**

Yes, a is numeric,  not an ts object, that's why I am using ts before stl.
When I plot tm and x.sa I got:

[image]

[image]

What am I missing??is the time object wrong?
I will put a sample (since the data is daily data for 10 years: 3653 observations), so, this would be a short sample:

```
mydata<- dput(a[1:40])
      c(281.127075195312, 280.629150390625, 282.007202148438, 280.685577392578, 
          278.718994140625, 281.126098632812, 279.95458984375, 280.4013671875, 
          278.469146728516, 274.627807617188, 277.929779052734, 276.451690673828, 
          275.632934570312, 277.067443847656, 277.834289550781, 280.159820556641, 
          280.40087890625, 280.572998046875, 278.621704101562, 279.200439453125, 
          279.614135742188, 278.984436035156, 276.867004394531, 272.86865234375, 
          275.842346191406, 278.622436523438, 277.736022949219, 277.709503173828, 
          282.733032226562, 281.467529296875, 282.947448730469, 282.413330078125, 
          281.055633544922, 281.113983154297, 281.544097900391, 282.1435546875, 
          281.356384277344, 281.776458740234, 281.724639892578, 280.923461914062
       )
```

Comment: What's `a`? Also, you've used `x.da` in your plot instead of `x.sa`. Neither you've mentioned the relevant packages. Other than that, this should work. Try for example `plot(AirPassengers,col="grey") ; lines(seasadj(stl(AirPassengers,s.window="periodic")),col="red")` and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: Ah, sorry there was a typo (x.da, is x.sa), and a is my dataset (i.e, str(a) num [1:3653] 281 281 282 281 279......). Even trying with the sentences you suggested I have the same plot :( ...

Comment: Please provide `dput(a)` to the question itself.

Comment: `a` is not a ts object. What happens if you plot `tm` and `x.sa` ?

Comment: You only provided 40 obs. But, if we will take a frequency of 7, for example. This code will work on the provided data `plot(ts(mydata, frequency = 7),col="grey") ; 
lines(seasadj(stl(ts(mydata, frequency = 7),s.window="periodic")),col="red")`

Comment: OK, thanks! I realised about my mistake, I had to plot(tm) instead a, which is not a ts object. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, you should certainly delete your "answer" or modify it to the correct answer.